# Difference in the output of query, using rank() and CTE

Tags: sql, hive, impala

My first query looks like:

```
select trans.* from
  ( select 
   acc_num,
   acc_type,
   trans_amount,
   load_date,
   rank() over(partition by acc_num order by load_date) as rk
   from monetary
   where rat_code = 123
 ) trans

where trans.rk =1;
```

second query looks like

```
with a as (
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by acc_num order by load_date) as rn
from monetary
where rat_code = 123 )
select 
acc_num,
acc_type,
trans_amount,
load_date
from a
where rn =1;
```

Can any one please help me I am getting different number of records for both the cases.
though the query is same.

Comment: How can you say the queries are the same when one uses RANK() and the other uses ROW_NUMBER()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because there is difference between rank and row_number.
Below example will show

```
Accno, dt, rank_col, rownum_col
100, 2-jun-2022, 1, 1
100, 3-jun-2022, 1, 2
100, 1-jul-2022, 1, 3
54, 2-jun-2022, 4, 1
54, 1-jul-2022, 4, 2
```

In above example, you can see row number will calculate unique row id. Whereas rank gives unique id but in a continuous manner. You can see from above example, rank=1 gives you 3 rows but rownum=1 gives only two.